# How to know if an Intel processor is a 4th or a 5th Core Generation Processor?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i3

I have recently bought a new Lenovo laptop having core i3 5th generation laptop. Is there any way to check if the processor is actually 5th gen not 4th gen. And what are the actual differences between these two?

Comment: 5th Gen processors start with 5 in their model number. 4th gen processors start with 4 in their model number. At least as far as laptops are concerned.

Comment: Intel gives this information at the web page
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html

Comment: Unless you purchase this device from a street vendor Lenovo would lose more money from selling selling you a fake product then they would save from selling you a fake product.  In other words the amount of crimes Lenovo would commit in order to do what you describe, advertise a product with a 5th generation CPU but it actually contains a 4th generation CPU, would take several dozen pages.  *Selling a fake product is illegal in most of the world.*

Answer (score 18):

Here is the answer to your question.  I had to take screenshots of the text since Intel's website refuses to let you copy and paste text from the table.

### 6th Generation Intel® Core™ Processor Family

[image]

[image]

### 5th Generation Intel® Core™ Processor Family

[image]

[image]

### 4th Generation Intel® Core™ Processor Family

[image]

[image]

[Source](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)

Comment: just to add, if its too small to read, click on the images.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look up your processor model then look it up on intel's webpage.

Go to control panel and system and it should show you what you have.

Something like [image]

On windows 10, just type in view processor info, and select what it searches for something like

[image]

So, in my case I have a 3770

googling that model leads me to [intel's ark site](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) (I google intel 3770 ark)

And your generation is on the side under related products

[image]

incidentally the first digit does seem to be the model number for 2nd generation and newer core processors.

Alternately [cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) gives you useful information on your processor and the *code name* and you can look up the code name

[image]

Comment: It is worth pointing out even the first generation can be identified by the model number.  They just used 3 digits instead of 4.  So a `960 i7` is a first generation core processor and thus 2700K is a 2nd generation core processor.  As you point out [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/) lists all of Intel's products.  In the example I used i7 960 comes from Core product line being the replacement for the [Pentium D](http://ark.intel.com/products/27522/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-960-4M-Cache-3_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) product line.

Comment: I assume "previous generation" means "first generation", since there is no "1st generation" listed? I have an i3 550, and it's listed as "previous generation"...

Comment: Hence my answer being a *process* rather than a simple answer. Google the model. a 550 sounds like a first generation core i processor tho